# Error when migration :: Could not find driver on MacOS

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have moved my Laravel project from Windows to MacOS and it is working perfectly with connecting to PostgreSQL database.

But when run "php artisan migrate" command, it showing following error message

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

When I check the phpInfo (I'm using PHP 7.3.27), it shows, PDO drivers for PostgreSQL (pdo_pgsql) is enabled.

How come this error trigger ONLY when I tried the migration command. All other functions are working perfectly.

Comment: Sometimes there are two different PHP versions installed on a machine, one for CLI and one for the web server.

Check your `phpinfo` what php.ini is being used and also run `php --ini` in your CLI and check if it's the same.

Comment: phpInfo => 7.3.27 and on CLI ==> 7.3.24. How to fix the issue ? Thanks :)

Comment: The one you checked on web i.e. `phpinfo` is 7.3.27 and the one you're trying to do artisan is `7.3.24`  according to your php version 7.3.24 should be enabled for driver. That tells us you either have two installations of php 5.6 or are using same installation but two different configuration files. the simplest solution would be to edit your CLI PHP config file and enable the pdo modules..

Comment: i can uncomment pdo_pgsql in the config file. But this file is not found in the extension folder. Where i can get this file OR how to install pdo_pgsql in mac ?

Comment: i'm not much of a `mac` guy but i believe you can try using the `php -i | grep .ini` command to find the required file.

Comment: seems by default MacOS has apache and php installed. So I had to set the default php to the one i have installed manually. Now both CLI and web php version are same. And now there is no error and worked as expected